# shell script can not save output from command line into variable

Tags: shell, variables, command-line, backticks

i'm trying to do shell command then save the output into variable using shell script. So i use backticks like this :

```
out=`ls -l`
print $out
```

that code is working fine,and i can use it for any other shell command, but when i try to do 'python --version' to check python version. i got weird problem. The backtick is not working for "python --version" command while it's working fine with any other commands, it  prints the output to the screen and save nothing to the variable $out. so if i do :

```
out =`python --version`
print "my python version is "$out
```

result:

```
Python 2.6.1
my python version is
```

also i tried to use $() to replace backtick , but no luck. Any idea ?

Comment: Bacticks are the old way of doing it.
Using $() is much more readable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a space before your equals sign:

```
out =`python --version`
```

Should be:

```
out=`python --version`
```

**Update**

Also python outputs the version string to stderr, so you need to redirect it to stdout:

```
out=`python --version 2>&1`
```

Comment: perfecto, Thanx a lot. now it works fine. Like you said , the problem is that python output it to stderr. out=\`python --version 2>&1\` works! Thanx.

Comment: I was working on writing a pre-commit hook and also couldn't figure out why the output wasn't being saved.  Your 2>&1 trick worked great! Thanks!